# Main thread doesn't wait background thread to finish in Swift

Tags: multithreading, swift, realm

Here's my problem : I'm doing a background work, where I parse some JSON and write some Objects into my Realm, and in the main thread I try to update the UI (reloading the TableView, it's linked to an array of Object). But when I reload the UI, my tableView doesn't update, like my Realm wasn't updated. I have the reload my View to see the updates. Here's my code :

```
    if (Realm().objects(Objects).filter("...").count > 0)
    {
        var results = Realm().objects(Objects) // I get the existing objects but it's empty
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    request(.GET, url).responseJSON() {
    (request, response, data, error) in
    let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
            // Parsing my JSON
            Realm().write {
                Realm().add(object)
            }
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                // Updating the UI
                if (Realm().objects(Objects).filter("...").count > 0)
                {
                    results = Realm().objects(Objects) // I get the existing objects but it's empty
                    tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have to do something bad with my threads, but I couldn't find what. Can someone know what's wrong?

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I recommend you use a notification block rather than sprinkling fetches and `reloadData()` throughout your view controller: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#notifications

Answer (score 3):

such workflow makes more sense to me for your case:

```
let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
    // Parsing my JSON
    Realm().write {
        Realm().add(object)
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            // Updating the UI
            if (Realm().objects(Objects).filter("...").count > 0)
            {
                results = Realm().objects(Objects) // I get the existing objects but it's empty
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

---

*NOTE: you have a problem with timing in your original workflow: the UI might be updated **before** the write's block executed, that is why your UI looks abandoned; this idea above would be a more synchronised way between tasks, according their performance's schedule.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didn't solve my problem.. Realm().objects(Objects) still returns me an empty array.

Comment: that issue might be outside of the snippet's scope you have presented, as the class `Realm` is unknown here, and it is quite odd why you call _class-level_ methods and what you are populating actually with the those objects – but you are definitely not populating an _instance-level_ array.

Comment: I'm simply using Realm for my internal database : https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/

Comment: I'm not really convinced (according to your snippet) about you have implemented and are using the `Realm.framework` properly in your code. try to log the results instead of trying to store them, and you will see where the problem is precisely.

Comment: I will try that, thanks. I just found this too : https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#background-operations. This is maybe the solution, i will try it.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting some new objects and storing them into "results".

How is tableView.reloadData () supposed to access that variable? You must change *something* that your tableView delegate will access.

PS. Every dispatch_sync () is a potential deadlock. You are using one that is absolutely pointless. Avoid dispatch_sync unless you have a very, very good reason to use it.

Comment: I didn't write the code of the delegate because I said it worked when i reload the view, but i have my "cellForRowAtIndexPath" which fills my cells with the content of the results. My problem is that results is empty when I get every "Objects", even if il wrote in my Realm in the background thread. Should't the main thread wait for the background thread to finish before doing is work?